# Asignar valor a fila de tabla jquery

Tags: jquery

Al armar un ticket, calculo el subtotal y los impuestos, etc.

Y tengo dos tablas:una con los articulos y otra de totales.
Como asigno el valor de la suma de los subtotales a una celda de la tabla totales:

```js
            success: function(data){

             if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){alert("sin articulos");}else{ 
                var subtotal = 0;
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                           
                           var newRow =
                                            "<tr>" +
                                          
                                            "<td>" + item.id + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + item.cantidad + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + item.nombre + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + item.precio + "</td>" +  
                                            
                                            "<td>" + item.subtotal + "</td>" +
                                            "</tr>";
                                     subtotal=subtotal + item.subtotal; 
                                          
                                        $(newRow).appendTo("#ticket tbody"); 
                                  
                                
                                
});
```

El subtotal me lo muestra enun alert perfecto. aqui el dom:

```html
<div class="row" style="vertical-align: left;">

    <table class="totales">

        <thead>
     
        <tr>
            <th>Subtotal.:</th>  <td><p id="sub"></p></td>
            
         </tr>   
         <tr>
         <th>IVA(21).:</th><td id="IVA">10</td>
           
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>Total.:</th><td id="total">10</td></tr>
        </thead>
       
    </table>
```

Por ejemplo identificar el td con id sub para asignarle el subtotal

Comment: muchas gracias..va perfecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genial pongo el comentario que funciono como respuesta

```
$("#sub").text(subtotal);
```

Saludos :)